# Passing text with escape characters from Jenkins into Groovy script

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to retrieve a username/password combination from Jenkins's credential store and pass it into a cURL.  This works completely fine until there's a special character in the password like "!" that will cause it to error out.

```
String url = ["https://stash.myorg.com/stash/rest/api/1.0/projects", projectKey,
              "repos", repoSlug, "browse", repoDirPath, filename].join("/")
url = url.replace(" ", "%20")

// call to helper function
final String srcCommitId = getPreviousCommitId(projectKey, repoSlug, branchName)

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: credId, usernameVariable: credUsername,
        passwordVariable: credPassword)]) {

    final String curl = 'curl -X PUT -u ' + credUsername + ':' + credPassword + ' -F content=@\"' +
            filename +'\" -F message="Revised document" -F branch=' +
            branchName + ' -F sourceCommitId=' + srcCommitId + ' ' + url


    dir (‘localpath/docs’) {
        
        def response
        response = sh(script: curl, returnStdout: true)
        println(response)
        
    }
}
```

I've tried to put the HTTP PUT through Jenkins's Http Plugin but it wants to post as an application/x-www-form-urlencoded and not as a normal form.  Any thoughts on how to escape the string so it doesn't error?  Thanks!

Comment: should we guess the error message or place where it happens?

Comment: Apologies... the error that is happening is that it does not interpret the password properly and fails in authentication.  If I have a password without a "!", it works fine.  {"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Authentication failed. Please check your credentials and try again.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.auth.IncorrectPasswordAuthenticationException"}]}.

Comment: groovy does not require `!` to be escaped. however in shell it does. try to escape `user:pass` into single quotes `'uesr:pass'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I figured this out and it's something dumb.  In the process of parameterizing the username/password, I dropped the "$".  Once I updated the code to the following below, everything worked fine.

```
final String curl = 'curl -X PUT -u $' + credUsername + ':$' + credPassword + ' -F content=@\"' +
        filename +'\" -F message="Revised document" -F branch=' +
        branchName + ' -F sourceCommitId=' + srcCommitId + ' ' + url
```